# Getting the error Cannot use instance member 'url' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, class, struct

i am trying to know why is this error appearing i'm curious whether or not it's because im using classes and structs in the same folder or not ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let url = "http://roadfiresoftware.com/feed/json"

    struct Blog: Decodable {
        let title: String
        let homepageURL: URL
        let articles: [Article]

        enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case title
            case homepageURL = "home_page_url"
            case articles = "items"
        }
    }

    struct Article: Decodable {
        let id: String
        let url: URL
        let title: String
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {

            NSLog("Error: No data to decode")
            return
        }

        guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Blog.self, from: data) else {
            NSLog("Error: Couldn't decode data into Blog")
            return
        }

        NSLog("blog title: \(blog.title)")
        NSLog("blog home: \(blog.homepageURL)")

        NSLog("articles:")
        for article in blog.articles {
            NSLog("- \(article.title)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: URLSession.shared.dataTask should come inside a method

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this particular line:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
```

You are trying to run a code block directly within a class, which you cannot do, this code needs to be contained within a code block, such as a method call.

I would suggest that wrap this logic within the `viewDidLoad()` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchBlog() 
}

func fetchBlog() {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {

            print("Error: No data to decode")
            return
        }

        guard let blog = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Blog.self, from: data) else {
            print("Error: Couldn't decode data into Blog")
            return
        }

        print("blog title: \(blog.title)")
        print("blog home: \(blog.homepageURL)")

        print("articles:")
        for article in blog.articles {
            print("- \(article.title)")
        }
    }
}
```

You could also call this function from other places such as init, viewWillAppear, from another function etc.

**NOTE**: Don't use NS classes such as NSLog in Swift unless you really need to, there is almost always a Swift version